# Successful running of an Ant script in "IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.3" does not display a proper message

Tags: intellij-idea

In previous versions of IntelliJ IDEA (like 10.5) when I successfully run an Ant script, I get a proper message like "Ant successfully done for 55s".

But now, in version 11.1.3 of IntelliJ, I don't get this kind of message, because there some warnings. I would like to suppress those warnings and just get the message that the script is done without errors.

Actually, some times I got a message like

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm using IDEA 12 EAP and see next "Ant build completed with 7 errors one warning in 1s at 20/08/12 12:59" when errors and "Ant build completed successfully in 1s at 20/08/12 13:00" when everything is OK

Comment: Check "Close message view if no error occurred" checkbox in "Build File Properties" window, if it checked - uncheck it. To access this window select your ant build(in ant tool-window) and press Alt+Enter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not what I'm looking for. I want the exact same behaviour like Eugen.
And I just can't understand what is different, except the version of IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [known bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-89717), please star/vote it in YouTrack to track the progress.